Jax tracer leaks
I have a JAX tracer leak problem when I start using vmap. I've got two functions grad_loss and its batched equivalent grad_loss_batch.
@eqx.filter_value_and_grad
def grad_loss(model, ti, yi):
    y_pred = model(ti, yi[0])
    return jnp.mean((yi - y_pred) ** 2)

@eqx.filter_value_and_grad
def grad_loss_batch(model, ti, yi):
    y_pred = jax.vmap(model, (None, 0))(ti, yi[:, 0])
    return jnp.mean((yi - y_pred) ** 2)

By running some preliminary experiments :
ts = jnp.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 10)
ys = jax.lax.stop_gradient(jnp.ones_like(ts)[..., None])
...

# seem to work ok 
with jax.checking_leaks():
   loss, grads = grad_loss(model_dde, ts, ys)

# Silently side-effecting, no error ?
loss2, grads2 = grad_loss_batch(model_dde, ts, ys[None, ...])

# Jax tracer leak
with jax.check_tracer_leaks():
    loss2, grads2 = grad_loss_batch(model_dde, ts, ys[None, ...])

The error yields :
(jdb) grad_loss_batch(model_dde, ts, ys[None, ...])
*** Exception: Leaked trace MainTrace(3,BatchTrace). Leaked tracer(s):

Traced<ShapedArray(float32[1])>with<BatchTrace(level=3/0)> with
  val = Array([[1.]], dtype=float32)
  batch_dim = 0
This BatchTracer with object id 132573553507072 was created on line:
  /home/monsel/Desktop/dev_diffrax/mwe.py:69 (grad_loss_batch)
<BatchTracer 132573553507072> is referred to by <list 132573501535936>[0]
<list 132573501535936> is referred to by <PjitParams 132573554102464>[0]
<PjitParams 132573554102464> is referred to by <InferParamsCacheEntry 132573553590720>

I was wondering if anyone could provide pointers in order to start debugging the problem. I know that the problem depends on model and its definition. I would rather put this as an abstraction since it is a fairly big codebase that the user would have to dig into. Nonetheless, I could provide a "large" MWE to reproduce this.

Tracer leaks generally happen when a function has a side-effect, such as storing a value in a cache that persists beyond the scope of the traced function. Here's a minimal example of this kind of tracer leak:
import jax

class Model:
  def __call__(self, x):
    self.cache = x  # persistently storing a traced value -> tracer leak
    return x
jax.tree_util.register_dataclass(Model, data_fields=[], meta_fields=[])

model = Model()
x = jax.numpy.arange(5)

with jax.check_tracer_leaks():
  jax.vmap(model)(x)

Exception: Leaked trace MainTrace(1,BatchTrace). Leaked tracer(s):

Traced<ShapedArray(int32[])>with<BatchTrace(level=1/0)> with
  val = Array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int32)
  batch_dim = 0
This BatchTracer with object id 133963186386912 was created on line:
  <ipython-input-14-2a0f2d1c7a01>:12 (<cell line: 12>)
<BatchTracer 133963186386912> is referred to by <Model 133963190222512>.cache
<Model 133963190222512> is referred to by <dict 133965063269504>['model']
<dict 133965063269504> is referred to by <frame 133964059882208>
<frame 133964059882208> is referred to by <list 133963186878784>[0]
<list 133963186878784> is referred to by <FramesList 133963188017072>._frames
<FramesList 133963188017072> is referred to by <frame 95552919519184>
<frame 95552919519184> is referred to by <generator 133963188390256>

I suspect whatever your model object is, it's probably doing something similar to this

Thanks for the quick sandbox example ! I'm unsure to completely follow how the error for tracing leaks would help a user. Would you have an explanation of how to interpret the error stack ? Here BatchTracer directly points to the leak<Model 133963190222512>.cache but in most cases this isn't the case ?
